# Read value from xml element which tag name contains colon (:) in c#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I extracted body data from soapResponse which is given by webservice. but am not able to extract from tags which contains colon between and below data is the body response.

XML Sample Data:

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://abc/envelope/"> 
      <soapenv:Header xmlns:view="http://abc/ViewCusReq" /> 
       <soapenv:Body xmlns:view="http://abc/ViewCusReq"> 
           <ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3="http://abc/ViewCusResp"> 
                <ns3:ReqID>123</ns3:ReqID> 
                <ns3:FName>ab</ns3:FName> 
           </ns3:Cus_Res> 
          <ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3="http://test.com/ViewCusResp"> 
                <ns3:ReqID>123</ns3:ReqID> 
                <ns3:FName>ab</ns3:FName> 
          </ns3:Cus_Res> 
        </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

used below c# code for about to get list of values of `ReqID` and `AbhiFNameav`, but it returns empty/null.

```
var responseEle = from lst in xDoc.Descendants((XNamespace)"http://test.com/ViewCusResp" + "ReqID") select lst;
```

I know, something i querying wrongly format, Can anyone help me out from this,. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Your XML isn't well formed (there's no closing `Cus_Res` and `FirstName` and `FName` don't match). Even if you fix these, you can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/91AOor) that your query works fine.

Comment: Excellent, this is the what i'm expecting, but if i want all values how can i change the query?

Comment: All values of what? You stated the problem was that the query returned `empty/null`, which it doesn't. So what's the *actual* problem?

Comment: Do you mean, there is more to xml ?

Comment: `<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://abc/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:view="http://abc/ViewCusReq" />
   <soapenv:Body xmlns:view="http://abc/ViewCusReq">
      <ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3="http://abc/ViewCusResp">
         <ns3:ReqID>123</ns3:ReqID>
         <ns3:FName>ab</ns3:FName>
      </ns3:Cus_Res>
     <ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3="http://test.com/ViewCusResp">
         <ns3:ReqID>123</ns3:ReqID>
         <ns3:FName>ab</ns3:FName>
      </ns3:Cus_Res>
   </soapenv:Body>`


This is actual response, i list ofneed both `ReqID` and `FName` values.

Comment: Don't post this in a comment, [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to make an answer without knowing if your xml is just a basic sample or if it is (once corrected) a true example of what you are working with in production. 
Will there be many `Cus_Res` nodes?

To answer your exact question see the code below that selects the nodes and gets the values. However, if your production xml is more complicated then you have more work to do looping over collections of `Cus_Res`, for example.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF - 8""?>
<ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3=""http://test.com/customerResponse"">
    <ns3:ReqID> 123456789 </ns3:ReqID>
    <ns3:FName> Abhinav </ns3:FName>
</ns3:Cus_Res>";

XNamespace xn = "http://test.com/customerResponse";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var reqid  = xDoc.Descendants(xn + "ReqID").First();
var fname = xDoc.Descendants(xn + "FName").First();

Console.WriteLine(reqid.Value);
Console.WriteLine(fname.Value);
```

> Update

If you had many `Cus_Res` nodes within a root element you would select all `Cus_Res` nodes then loop over them, accessing it's direct children.

Again, it would not take much modification to your xml to break this and you should also do null checking which I do not demonstrate:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF - 8""?>
<root>
    <ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3=""http://test.com/customerResponse"">
        <ns3:ReqID> 123456789 </ns3:ReqID>
        <ns3:FName> Abhinav </ns3:FName>
    </ns3:Cus_Res>
    <ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3=""http://test.com/customerResponse"">
        <ns3:ReqID> 3456 </ns3:ReqID>
        <ns3:FName> Wayne </ns3:FName>
    </ns3:Cus_Res>
    <ns3:Cus_Res xmlns:ns3=""http://test.com/customerResponse"">
        <ns3:ReqID> 78952</ns3:ReqID>
        <ns3:FName>Garth</ns3:FName>
    </ns3:Cus_Res>
</root>";

XNamespace xn = "http://test.com/customerResponse";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var CurResList = xDoc.Descendants(xn + "Cus_Res");

foreach (XElement element in CurResList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Element(xn + "ReqID").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(element.Element(xn + "FName").Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Crowcoder , This looks so cool, `First()` function returns only first item, what code is need to be change if body returns list of elements.

Comment: See update for example scenario of many nodes.

Comment: @lucky I just noticed the comment you posted to your question. If you are working with SOAP you can typically generate a client proxy and work with .net objects instead of XML. Additionally, in my experience, the namespace of SOAP responses can change between clients so parsing xml could possibly be fragile.

Comment: Yes,  i have tried in that way of creating proxy. Proxy is not able to create classes as per services and request and response in XML format only, so i choosed `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest` way. is there any other better way than this?

Comment: @lucky I'm not sure I understand your comment, but when you use a proxy it is supposed to abstract the xml so you don't have to deal with it.